# Optimization problem on trace with both the positive semi definite and non positive semidefinite matrix

Tags: global-optimization, orthogonal-matrices

Given two $N \times N$ symmetric matrices  $A, B$, where $A$ is positive semidefinite while $B$ is not positive semidefinite. I am interested in solving unitary constrained trace maximization problem:

$\arg \max_{U}\text{trace}(UAU^TB),\;\;$      subject to $\;U^TU=I.$

When the matrix  $B$ is positive semidefinite and diagonal the solution set $U$ will be the ordered eigenvectors of $A$. But in my case the matrix $B$ is surely nonpositive definite.

Answer (score 3):

$\DeclareMathOperator{tr}{tr}$
$\DeclareMathOperator{grad}{grad}$
$\DeclareMathOperator{sym}{sym}$

New answer:

WLOG, We can assume that $B$ is positive definite. Since for every orthogonal matrix $U$, we have

$$ \tr(UAU^T(B+\lambda I)) = \tr(UAU^TB) + \lambda \tr(A)$$

So if we use $B+\lambda I$ (for sufficiently large $\lambda$) instead of $B$, the optimal solution set were not changed.

---

Old answer:

Let us, first, find critical points of the problem. One can see the problem as an unconstrained optimization problem on the manifold of orthogonal matrices. So first order optimality conditions are $\grad f(U) = 0$, where $\grad$ stand for the Riemannian gradient of $f(U) := \tr(UAU^TB)$ on the orthogonal matrices. 
We have $\grad f(U) = 2AU^TB-2U^T \sym(UAU^TB)$, where $\sym$ is the symmetric part of a matrix. 
Now, necessary optimality conditions reduce to 
 $B$ commutes with $UAU^T$.
So when $B$ is a diagonal matrix (not necessarily semi-positive definite) with distinct elements, $UAU^T$ is diagonal and columns of $U^T$ are eigenvectors of $A$.

Comment: Thanks for an elaborate reply. However, I have some confusion about the conclusion that $B$ and $UAU^T$ are commutative.   Could you please provide some references for more insight for the Riemannian gradient?

Comment: You're welcome.  [**Optimization Algorithms on
Matrix Manifolds**](http://www.eeci-institute.eu/GSC2011/Photos-EECI/EECI-GSC-2011-M5/book_AMS.pdf)  is a standard book. Particularly techniques of  Section 4.8 maybe helpful.

Comment: Thanks again for an excellent reference. I just followed the analysis of the section 4.8. Now, I  tottaly unedrstand your explanation for the solution. But still I have a minor confusion. In the analysis the result that $UAU^T$ is commutative with $B$ is fine. But for the result the critical point $U$ is the eigenvectors of $A$, the derivation requires $B$ to be invertible and diagonal. But in my case though  $B$ is diagonal but it has both the negative and zero values. I am wondering whether the solution will be the same without the inevrtiblity assumption on $B$.

Comment: The solution will be the same if diagonal elements of $B$ are distinct.

Comment: Oh great! I have the distinct diagonal elements for $B$.

Comment: Your explanation is very elegant and intuitive. Thanks again. For the same problem structure in another application, I have to deal with repetitive values of the diagonal matrix $B$. Now we have $B$(Diagonal with 0 and negative entries, and 0 is repetitive). What could be the possible strategy to solve this problem.

Answer (score 3):

For Hermitian matrices $A$ and $B$, we know that the following inequality holds:
\begin{equation*}
\text{tr}(AB) \le \langle \lambda^{\downarrow}(A), \lambda^{\downarrow}(B)\rangle,
\end{equation*}
where $\lambda^{\downarrow}(\cdot)$ denotes the eigenvalues arranged in decreasing order. Using this inequality we see that to maximize the innerproduct, $U^T$ should be the eigenvectors of $A$ (suitably ordered).

Comment: Perfect, neat and precise. Thanks a lot

Comment: You are welcome (both: Mahdi and Sandeep)

Comment: Hi, Survit and Mahdi, thanks again for the valuable suggestions regarding manifold optimization. The discussion held here was really helpful in finalizing my research on graph learning algorithms. I am happy to share with you the resulting work.  

Title: A Unified Framework for Structured Graph Learning via Spectral Constraints: https://arxiv.org/abs/1904.09792 
An R package software containing the experimental codes:  https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/spectralGraphTopology/


I will be very happy to receive feedback and suggestions.
Thanks again!